# How to test a method which returns a promise in sinon?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, sinon

I have the following controller:

```
app.controller('SearchVideosController',

function SearchVideosController($scope, videoRepository) {

  $scope.DoSearch(id, text) {

    // Do some work...

    videoRepository.getVideosForUserBasedOnSearchText(id,text)
                       .then(function(data){
                          // Do something with the data.
                       });

   };

};
```

My videoRepository.getVideosForUserBasedOnSearchText() method uses $q and I want to create stub to ensure that the call is made.

I tried :

```
 it("should have 3 searched videos", function(){
  ...
    mockVideoRepository.getVideosForUserBasedOnSearchText.returns([]);
```

but get .then() is undefined.

Not sure how to handle the then() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to get hold of `$q` service instance and use `$q.when` to create a promise wrapped value:-

```
mockVideoRepository.getVideosForUserBasedOnSearchText.returns($q.when([]));
```

Also remember you would need to manually perform a digest cycle in your test before the expecation to evaluate the result of the `getVideosForUserBasedOnSearchText` call. Only when a digest cycle is invoked  promise will be resolved in your test. You can do it by getting hold of scope, and perform `$digest` or `$apply`. Example:- `rootScope.$apply()`